# Error: No Matching Constructor when trying to construct a templated object from a vector value

Tags: c++

I have the following templated classes `MyObject` and `SmallObject`. Below, I have a constructor for a `MyObject` that takes a vector as input and converts each item in the vector into a `SmallObject`. However, when it runs in tests, it returns an error for no matching constructor.

I can't tell what is wrong, my guess was that somehow the values I'm pulling from the vector are not of type T, but I don't understand how this could be the case. This is also a simplified snippet of the relevant parts so don't worry about the fact it's not doing anything with the SmallObj and leaking memory

```
template<typename T>
SmallObj<T>::SmallObj(T& value) : _value(value) {}

template<typename T>
MyObject<T>::MyObject(const std::vector<T>& values) {
  int n = values.size();

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    SmallObject<T>* node = new SmallObject<T>(values[i]); // error: no matching constructor
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a wild, wild guess, but `SmallObject` may not be the same thing as `SmallObj`?

Comment: `values[i]` will be a `const T&` but the constructor accepts `T&`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ahh oops that was just a problem with me writing up the question, thank you for catching that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `values` is passed as reference to `const`, then `values[i]` returns `const T&`. While the constructor of `SmallObj` takes reference to non-const which can't bind to constant. If it's not supposed to modify the argument you can change the constructor to take reference to `const`.

```
template<typename T>
SmallObj<T>::SmallObj(const T& value) : _value(value) {}
```